# Adding e.preventDefault(); to disable anchor behavior broke function

Tags: jquery

I'm pretty stumped on this because it seems so simple. I took this function:

```
$('#nav-link-1').click(function(){
     $('#nav-pulldown-div-1').slideToggle();
});
```

...and changed it to this (in line with what I've seen other people doing to disable the anchor's default behavior):

```
$('#nav-link-1').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#nav-pulldown-div-1').slideToggle();
});
```

...and it completely stopped working. (The nav-pulldown-div-# divs should toggle into view when the link is clicked.) I'm still not too well versed with JQuery, so I can only imagine I'm overlooking something simple.

EDIT: Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GrByz/2/

I know it's weird there's only links 2 and 3, but there's a reason for that in the design.

Comment: Can you show some fiddle ?

Comment: I'm going to assume that it used to scroll until the navigation link was in view?

Comment: Completely stopped working is quite descriptive!

Comment: i commented out the prevent defualts i see nothing different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo on fiddle. You are missing `.` in

```
$('#nav-link-3').click(function(e) {
    $('#nav-pulldown-div-3').slideToggle();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Oh jeez. Yeah, you're right, that was it. I feel pretty stupid right now.

Answer (score 1):

on line 12 of your jsFiddle you had this:

```
$('#nav-link-3')click(function(e) {
```

if you correct that syntax by adding the `.` before `click`...

```
$('#nav-link-3').click(function(e) {
```

then it seems to work fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/GrByz/3/

Answer (score 0):

[image]

That is because there is no Element with an ID value of `nav-link-1`